# rate limiting celery task group

Tags: python, celery

Currently I am limiting individual tasks but want to limit all of them together as a group.  I have not see in documents how to accomplish this.

```
CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {"tasks.aws_install_cwagent": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_create_parameters": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_config_cwagent": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_describe_alarms": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_list_aliases": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_list_keys": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_describe_volumes": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_describe_instances": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_describe_target_groups": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_describe_target_health": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_describe_load_balancers": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_get_platform": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_write_log_message": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_list_metrics": {"rate_limit":"2/s"},
                  "tasks.aws_put_metric_alarm": {"rate_limit":"2/s"}}
```

Is there a way to rate limit all these tasks as a group? So for instance celery is allowed to run all at 10/s?

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this can be handled with celery configuration options, but you can manually do such thing

```
AWS_TASKS = (
    "tasks.aws_install_cwagent",
    "tasks.aws_create_parameters",
)
AWS_COMMON_OPTIONS = {"rate_limit": "2/s"}
CELERY_ANNOTATIONS.update({task: AWS_COMMON_OPTIONS for task in AWS_TASKS})
```

**UPDATE**

With `CELERY_ANNOTATIONS` you also can set settings for every task (`'*'`) or every task that satisfies some statement. Here is examples:

```
# for every task
CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {'*': {'rate_limit': '2/s'}}
```

```
# custom statement, in this example - every task starts with 'tasks.aws'
class MyAnnotate:
    def annotate(self, task):
        if task.name.startswith('tasks.aws'):
            return {'rate_limit': '2/s'}

CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = (MyAnnotate(), {…})
```

docs: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-annotations

Comment: Doesn’t this just set 2/s per task like I was doing?  Not 2 for the group of tasks?

Comment: @user1601716 yea this code actually does the same thing, but instead to set rate_limit for every task, you setting it for pre-defined group called `AWS_TASKS`, you can also define your custom `Annotate` class if you want to set rate_limit (or other settings) for every task, lets say, that name starts with `tasks.aws_*`, see `UPDATE` section of my answer for details

Comment: Cool will check it out